# ggplot2: making symbols in legend match symbols in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to do a plot that has most data points drawn normally, but one set of data points with a different sized symbol. I want the legend to show the same: most points shown normally, but the exception drawn with a different sized symbol. Here is a short bit of code:

```
library(ggplot2)
x = c(1,2,1,2,3)
y = c(1,2,3,4,3)
vendor = c("x", "x", "y", "y", "z")
df = data.frame(x,y,vendor)

p <- ggplot(df) +
     aes_string(x="x", y="y", color="vendor") +
     geom_point(size=3, data=subset(df, vendor!="z")) +
     geom_point(size=5, data=subset(df, vendor=="z"))
ggsave("foo.pdf")
```

The problem is that in the resulting legend, *all* points are drawn with the larger (`size=5`) symbol, not just those with vendor z. I want vendor z drawn with the larger point in the legend, and the others drawn with `size=3`.

(Bonus question: What I really want is a larger thick outlined symbol: instead of a circle, I want a donut. I realize that `shape=2` will draw an outlined circle, but it is very thin. I'd rather have a thicker outlined circle. I want to do the same with a triangle. Any easy way to do this?)

Maybe I applied it wrong, but following this advice:

[ggplot2: Making changes to symbols in the legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751159/ggplot2-making-changes-to-symbols-in-the-legend)

with the addition of the "guides" line did not help:

```
guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 1)))
```

i.e. same output, with `size=5` symbols for all three vendors in the legend.

EDITED: Fantastic answer, which I quickly implemented. Now I've added lines:

```
library(ggplot2)
x = c(1,2,1,2,3)
y = c(1,2,3,4,3)
vendor = c("x", "x", "y", "y", "z")
df = data.frame(x,y,vendor)

df$vendor_z <- df$vendor=="z"     # create a new column 

ggplot(df) +
  aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", color = "vendor", size = "vendor_z") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(size=1.5) +   # this is the only difference
  scale_size_manual(values = c(3, 5), guide = FALSE) 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = c(3, 3, 5))))

ggsave("foo.pdf")
```

and now the size of the legend is back down to 3 again for all dots, including the ones with vendor z. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: BTW I'm a total R n00b so feel free to critique my code and help me make it better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size is not applied to the legend since `size` is outside `aes_string`. Furtermore, the work with `ggplot` will be much easier if you create an additional column indicating whether `vendor == "z"`.

Here's a solution for part 1:

```
df$vendor_z <- df$vendor=="z"     # create a new column 

ggplot(df) +
  aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", color = "vendor", size = "vendor_z") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(3, 5), guide = FALSE) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = c(3, 3, 5))))
```

Note that `vendor_z` is as argument of `aes_string`. This will tell `ggplot` to create a legend for the `size` characteristic. In the function `scale_size_manual`, the values for `size` are set. Furthermore, `guide = FALSE` avoids a second legend for `size` only. Finally, the `size` values are applied to the `color` legend.

[image]

Part2: a "donut" symbol

The size of the lines for circles cannot be modified in `ggplot`. Here is a workaround:

```
ggplot(df) +
  aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", color = "vendor", size = "vendor_z") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = df[df$vendor_z, ], aes(x = x, y = y),
             size = 3, shape = 21, fill = "white", show_guide = FALSE) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(3, 5), guide = FALSE) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = c(3, 3, 5))))
```

Here, a single point is drawn using `geom_point` and a subset of the data (`df[df$vendor_z, ]`). I chose a `size` of `3` since this is the value of the smaller circles. The `shape` `21` is a circle for which a `fill` colour could be specified. Finally, `show_guide = FALSE` avoids that the legend characteristics are overwritten by the new `shape`.

[image]

*Edit*: part 3: Add lines

You could suppress the legend for `geom_line` with the argument `show_guide = FALSE`:

```
ggplot(df) +
  aes_string(x = "x", y = "y", color = "vendor", size = "vendor_z") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(size=1.5, show_guide = FALSE) +   # this is the only difference
  scale_size_manual(values = c(3, 5), guide = FALSE) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = c(3, 3, 5))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sven! What a great answer. I added a bit to the question to ask how to make this work with geom_line as well.

Comment: And on the donut ... any way to make the donut also show up in the legend? Good hack, drawing the white atop the blue circle.

Comment: @jowens I extendend the answer with a solution including lines. Drawing the white atop the blue circle for one out of three symbols in the legend would be difficult and may involve a hack outside ggplot. If I would find an answer, I'll let you know.

Comment: A very thoughtful and kind answer, and happily accepted. Things that I would like to see if anyone wanted to chime in: 1) I actually do care about the lines in the legend; in my full graph I have solid and dashed lines; 2) it would seem more general in the code if I didn't have to hardcode size=c(3,3,5), since if I add another vendor's data, I have to change this by hand; 3) what I'm really doing here is showing that vendor z is an exceptional case for vendor y, so I want z to look mostly like y but slightly different, and not connected to y's line.

Comment: And if anyone wants to take a look at the actual problem I'm trying to solve, I posted a brief readme with source and the resulting graph at http://tinyurl.com/dyhcxh7 .

Comment: The `guide` argument in `scale_*()` cannot be `FALSE`. This was deprecated in ggplot2 3.3.4. Please use "none" instead. Just FYI for others :)